# Extract JSON with php

Tags: php, json, api, geoip

Trying to get IP geolocation from whoisxmlapi to work. When I'm using the sample code they provide, everything is working fine. Here is the code I use.

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"];
    $api_key = 'your_api_key';
    $api_url = 'https://geoipify.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1';

    $url = "{$api_url}?apiKey={$api_key}&ipAddress={$ip}";

    print(file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

Here is the output I get printed on my page.

```
{"ip":"174.222.131.171","location":{"country":"US","region":"California","city":"Fresno","lat":36.74773,"lng":-119.77237,"postalCode":"93650","timezone":"-07:00"}}
```

Then, when I try to echo region only with following code, there is absolutely nothing on the page

```
$url = "{$api_url}?apiKey={$api_key}&ipAddress={$ip}";
$ipfeed = json_decode($url);
echo $ipfeed->region;
```

UPDATE:
error log record

[Mon Sep 17 18:20:01.101218 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6803] [client 127.0.0.1:34987] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'region' in /home/url.com/app/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-ads-plugin/custom-ads.php on line 191\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(h): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/url.com/app/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-ads-plugin/custom-ads.php on line 191\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'region' in /home/url.com/app/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-ads-plugin/custom-ads.php on line 191\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(h): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/url.com/app/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-ads-plugin/custom-ads.php on line 191\n'

Comment: Region is in another object named location. Try `$ipfeed->location->region;`

Comment: nope. Didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do `json_decode` on a "string url"... you need to decode the contents of the url. Then do:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"];
$api_key = 'your_api_key';
$api_url = 'https://geoipify.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1';

$url = "{$api_url}?apiKey={$api_key}&ipAddress={$ip}";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$ipfeed = json_decode($json);
echo $ipfeed->location->region;
```